# Reverse Engineer Slack Workspace

Tags: assembly

Is there any Slack workspace for Reverse Engineer experts?
I wanna to communicating other people who work in this issue.
I am thankful if you know this workspace and invite me.

Comment: Would discord fit ? https://discord.gg/weKN5wb

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot.